# How to display part of django object model?

Tags: python, django, web, typeerror, iterable

I'm trying to show a field of my database in `Django`, when user is not Superuser,
given an Field like `GR96 0810 0010 0000 0123 4567 890`,
the value should be displayed as `---7890` everywhere and this is my code :

```
view.py: 

def index(request):
    obj = MyModel.objects.all()
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return render(request, 'app/index.html', {'obj': obj})
    else:
        obj = len(str(obj))-5
        return render(request, 'app/index.html', {'obj': obj})

Template:
{% for ele in obj %}
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{ ele.id }}</th>
      <td>{{ ele }}</td>
    </tr>
{%  endfor %}


This is error:
TypeError at /
'int' object is not iterable

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     3.0
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

'int' object is not iterable
....
```

Could you please help me?
Thank you in advance

Comment: in first `if` you nave not obj but query set (iterable objects sequence). The `else` part contains only one obj. while rendering you are trying iterate over not iterable object. that because you have an exception. change second `obj` to iterablesequence (use list for ex.)

Comment: Could you provide your model?

Comment: In the `else`-case `obj` is not the `MyModel`, it is a number, since you calculate `len(str(obj))-5`.\

Comment: I see, but i tested several codes to export a valid and correct ele ....Then what should I do for That (if ... else...) statment?

Comment: @Zoleikha: Please check my answer below and let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

**obj** is a list of objects of type **MyModel**.

In your **else** condition:

```
obj = len(str(obj))-5
```

you are changing obj to an integer. You should instead do this:

`for idx, o in enumerate(obj):
     obj[idx].id = o[len(str(o.id)) - 5:]`

This extracts the last 5 characters from each of the MyModel objects inside **obj**.

Comment: I this situation error fixed, but  it shows nothing:

Comment: Yes, My Object include queryset of List and should be displayed as "---5455"

Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
<QuerySet []>
[13/Dec/2019 10:05:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 525

I tryed: obj = obj[len(list(obj)) - 5:]  
but now that if statement not works...and show all of data

Comment: Updated my answer, please check again.

Answer (score 0):

In the else statement you redeclared the obj as an integer value so you can't iterate through it in template. My suggestion to edit the return value when user is super admin:

view.py:

```
def index(request):
    obj = MyModel.objects.all()
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return render(request, 'app/index.html', {'obj': obj})
    else:
        for single_obj in obj:
           single_obj.your_field_name = "--" + single_obj.your_field_name.replace(" ", "")[-4:]
        return render(request, 'app/index.html', {'obj': obj})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, I fixed it, I should use "value_to_string()" in my Model.